# HTML syntax highlighting in FreeMarker/Velocity on Intellij

Tags: html, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, velocity

Intellij IDEA is already very good at syntax highlighting `.vm` Velocity files or independent `.html` files. But very often one uses template engines to create something in HTML format. Is there any way to enable this mixed mode syntax highlighting, like the one we have for JSP technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you [specify the language for your templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-data-languages.html)?

Comment: Great. Just found out that it is available just with a single right click!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to assign syntax highlighting using "File Type" option as mentioned in [the doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-data-languages.html) as "FreeMarker Template" language was not available in the language dropdown.

So I followed [this doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#configure-associations-between-filename-patterns-and-file-types) to assign a file type on a file name extension using below steps:

1. Go to the file in the file tree.
2. Right click on the file.
3. Click on the option <kbd>Associate with File Type</kbd> or choose `File | File Properties | Associate with File Type` from the main menu.
4. Enter file pattern if not auto populated.
5. Choose language "FreeMarker Templates" from the language dropdown under "Open matching files in IntelliJ IDEA" option.
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>